# Events occur only after construction?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events

I try to understand why i can't invite event in the last line of constructor?
Does the event "formload" occur after construction ends?

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        button1.Text = "a";
        button1.PerformClick();
    }

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Text = "b";
    }
```

Comment: `Does the event "formload" occur after construction ends?` It does. The `Load` event is triggered when the form  becomes visible, not when it's constructed.

Comment: Consider a button1_Click_Helper class that does the actual work and call the helper directly.

Comment: @Blam You don't need to make a helper method to do that.  You could just execture the `button1_Click` method as it is.

Comment: @Servy But executing the method as it is is not working.

Comment: @Blam he's not executing the method as it is, he's using `PerformClick` to fire the event, rather than just calling the method that he is also assigning to the event handler.

Answer (score 2):

This behavior is because if controls are built on the windows messages, which only works if the form instance exists and has a handle, which is not while it is still built.

The form must be open to be sure that the controls are working properly.

And it's not best practise to raise event on your constructor

Answer (score 0):

Tested.  Not dependent on the control created.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    button1.Text = "A";
    button1_Click_helper();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1_Click_helper();
}

private void button1_Click_helper()
{
    button1.Text = "B";
}
```

Comment: You could just add `button1_Click(this, new EventArgs())` to the constructor; you don't need a helper method.